# Word to express whether a field of study is invented or discovered

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Today I was discussing how Computer Science is different from e.g. Physics because the architecture of computers was designed and improved by humans, while the laws of physics are figured out through experimentation.

This got me thinking: is there a word that expresses this difference?

Comment: There is the distinction between [_natural_ vs. _formal_ science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_science). The natural sciences include physical and biological phenomena. The formal sciences include mathematics, logics, etc. along with theoretical computer sciences. You can read more about the distinction, which is not exactly what you described but similar.

Comment: Note also that Wikipedia classifies [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) and [computer engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_engineering) as [_applied_ sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_science), which are sciences that apply knowledge from the fundamental sciences to more practical applications.

Comment: @vanderpn WP classifies theoretical computer science, information theory, decision theory and theoretical linguistics as formal science; these all clearly study man-made subjects, so I guess computer science in general fits within that category. (That said, natural science isn't so clear-cut either; if you study the physical properties of a man-made material, are you studying a natural phenomenon or a human invention?)

Comment: @vanderpn what about making your answer... an answer? ;-)

Comment: @MasterScrat, I would if I could find a source other than Wikipedia that seemed reliable. If someone else wants to go digging, feel free to take my comment and turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you view a subject as being *invented* and *discovered* is called your [epistemic attitude](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-realism/) to a subject.

---

**TL/DR**

If you are going to compare computer science and physics in this way, then you need to think about things differently.

The design and architecture of computers can only be compared to the design and architecture of the instruments used by physicist, not to the subject of physics itself.

Whether or not the subjects of physics and computer science are *invented* or *discovered* is a philosophical question.  In physics, this dichotomy is expressed in the terms *realist* (discovered) and *anti-realist* (invented).  In computer science and mathematics the terms *Platonist* (discovered) and *formalist* (invented) are used.

Most computer scientists will be Platonists, believing they are *discovering* the nature of computation, just as most physicist believe they are *discovering* the nature of reality.  So computer scientists and physicists share the same *epistemic attitude*.

On the other hand, most of those people designing computers and instruments for physicists will take the view that they are *inventing* technologies and thus, again, share the same *epistemic attitude*.

Answer (score 0):

A science that discovers things is **empirical**:

> Empirical evidence, also known as sense experience, is the knowledge
>   or source of knowledge acquired by means of the senses, particularly
>   by observation and experimentation. The term comes from the Greek word
>   for experience, ἐμπειρία (empeiría). After Immanuel Kant, it is common
>   in philosophy to call the knowledge thus gained a posteriori knowledge
>   (in contrast to a priori knowledge). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence)

A science that uses reason (such as pure mathematics) would presumably be rational or a priori.

A science that invents things would be technical